# i want to parse this JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I want to parse this JSON in PHP. I don't know how to parse data it:

```
  stdClass Object ( 
    [coord] => stdClass Object ( 
      [lon] => 138.93 
      [lat] => 34.97 
    ) 
    [weather] => Array (
      [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 803 
        [main] => Clouds 
        [description] => broken clouds 
        [icon] => 04n 
      )
    ) 
    [base] => stations 
    [main] => stdClass Object ( 
      [temp] => 290.738 
      [pressure] => 1026.59 
      [humidity] => 94 
      [temp_min] => 290.738 
      [temp_max] => 290.738 
      [sea_level] => 1035.92 
      [grnd_level] => 1026.59 ) 
      [wind] => 
        stdClass Object ( 
          [speed] => 6.81 
          [deg] => 225.502 ) 
          [clouds] => stdClass Object ( 
            [all] => 56 ) 
          [dt] => 1460799951 
          [sys] => stdClass Object ( 
            [message] => 0.0131 
            [country] => JP 
            [sunrise] => 1460751040 
            [sunset] => 1460798268 
          ) 
          [id] => 1851632 
          [name] => Shuzenji 
          [cod] => 200 
    )
```

Comment: I don't know any PHP or JSON, but I can downvote this:(

Comment: ok,,then how to take the main part?

Comment: No idea what you want to do here.

Answer (score 1):

That's not jSON, it's a PHP Object.

To fetch it, you can use `->` like this for instance. Say it is in `$data` var and you want to get the weather array :

```
$weather = $data -> weather; // retrieve weather array
```

To get `main` Object part, you can do as follow :

```
$mainObject = $data -> main; // retrieve main Object
$temp = $data -> main -> temp; // retrieve temp from main Object
```

Comment: more specification plz

Comment: i want to take main object's part ,,then what to do?

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to validate it to close the subject :)